# Page reloads before reaching else statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, local-storage, reload

The problem in the code below resides in the if...else statement. If a user tries to create an account with a username or email already present in localStorage the program displays an error message. This works fine however if the if statement is false the page reloads before reaching the else statement. I have used console.log to check whether the else statement is run however as stated above the page reloads before ever reaching the else statement. I have also tried putting event.preventDefault in the if statement however that doesnt work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: the function is called using onclick in html when the button is pressed.

```
 function storeRegistrationInfo(){
            let person = {};
            person.fullname = document.getElementById("regFullName").value;
            person.username = document.getElementById("regUserName").value;
            let username = document.getElementById("regUserName").value;
            person.email = document.getElementById("regEmail").value;
            person.password = document.getElementById("regPassword").value;
            person.repeatedPassword = document.getElementById("repeatPassword").value;

            let per = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(username));

            if (person.username === per.username || person.email === per.email){
                document.getElementById("signUpStatus").innerText = "Username or Email already taken!";
            }else {
                localStorage[person.username] = JSON.stringify(person);
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry the method is called using the onclick function when the sign up button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Andre, you are not receiving the event object.

Assume you are triggering this as part of onClick() ?
Try adding :

```
function storeRegistrationInfo(event)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work .... event is a property of window however and it works in other methods without an event parameter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need to add:

```
if( !(person === undefined)  &&(person.username === per.username || person.email === per.email))
```